# Feature Image widget has disappeared after upgrade to 4.2.1

Tags: wordpress

Hiall,

I upgraded to Wordpress 4.2.1 yesterday but now my Feature Image widget (the default wordpress one on the right side) has just disappeared!

I have deactivated all plugins tried it again, but still it's gone.

I also looked in the screen options and there is no option for it!

Any help would be great, will be the last time I upgrade early to a WP update.

Comment: Still stuck on this if anyone can help? The theme is built from scratch the ground up,  already have added

     // Add Widget Area
     function ourWidgetsInit() {

     register_sidebar( array(
     'name' => 'Sidebar',
     'id' => 'sidebar1',
     'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-item">',
     'after_widget' => '</div>',
     'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
     'after_title' => '</h2>',
     ));

     add_action('widgets_init', 'ourWidgetsInit');

Inside my functions.php???

Any other ideas?

Comment: fixed this by moving the line add_theme_support('post-thumbnails'); right towards the top of my functions.php file, 4.2.1 must be reading it a bit differently or something